# How to programmatically end ASP.Net Core app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, lifecycle

In order to make sure my code does not interfere with anything the "Startup" looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  return;
  ...

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  return;
  ...
```

And in program I added following code to evaluate programmatic ending of the app:

```
IHost host = BuildHost(args); // custom method

IHostLifetime lifetime = (IHostLifetime)host.Services.GetService(typeof(IHostLifetime));
Task.Run(async () =>
{
  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).ConfigureAwait(false);
  Console.WriteLine($"Stopping at {DateTimeOffset.Now}");
  await lifetime.StopAsync(CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
  Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
});

host.Run();

Console.WriteLine("THE END");
```

When I run it, ASP.NET Core app starts as usual, then after one minute `StopAsync` is called, and just a second later I see message "Stopped" on console. The problem is I don't see the final message ("THE END") so it is not really stopped.

So how to end it correctly?

Comment: Is your custom `BuildHost` method similar to the `CreateHostBuilder(args).Build() ` generated in Program.cs;？Why don't you use `await host.StopAsync(CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);` directly in `Task.Run `?

Comment: @Chen, ha! This is good, after reading about IHostLifetime (and other related types injected by default) I was under the impression it is the right way and only way :-). Using `host` works, thank you.